# How to install android market app manually?

Tags: google-play-store

I have device with android 2.1 and I want to install android market app manually. Can I do that?

I have download android_app.apk file into my device but while installing getting following error. 
**Package com.android.market_app requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.datamessaging; failing!** 
I tried to search datamessaging.jar file but I can not able to find.
Does I need to do something else.

Comment: Which device is this for?

Comment: is market app is device specific or android version specific or both?

Answer (score 1):

If you have wi-fi or 3G you can install it through AppBrain [Andoid market App](http://www.appbrain.com/app/android-market/am.am)

In case if you dont have any network connection you have to find the .pkg (compiled android package) for Android market application, then you need to install it via [ADB](http://voxigee.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/using-adb-to-install-applications/)

Comment: I have install android_app.apk file into my device but I was getting error. Package com.android.market_app requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.datamessaging; failing!

Comment: How did you install it, with adb or some other way???

Comment: using adb install command