# HTC Desire Z without Android Market?

Tags: google-play-store, htc-desire-z

I bought a HTC Desire Z from UAE (United Arab Emirates) country. Surprisingly, there isn't the Android Market in the Applications list! I tried to install Market manually, but it crashes and terminates. Without Market I'm unable to install new applications or upgrade existing ones.

Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Market is currently blocked in UAE and this has nothing to do with your phone. [It may become available soon](http://arabcrunch.com/2011/02/android-market-coming-to-uae-egypt-turkey-and-saudi-arabia.html) but I've not found anything with a date. I have seen that it's not so much the government blocking it as an inability to bring banks on-board.

[This thread](http://samsunggalaxysforums.com/showthread.php/892-Don-t-have-Android-Market-Don-t-worry-here-is-your-solution!) suggests that you can get around it with a dial code, but it looks like it needs a hard reset. There are also other questions here about installing the app manually, like: [How to install android market app manually?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7983/how-to-install-android-market-app-manually)

Comment: I have to root my phone, finally! :D

Comment: I've installed cyanogenmod 7. It's GREAT! :D

Answer (score -2):

every [Android phone](http://www.lovebargaining.com/-Discount-cell-phone-android-cell-phone_c801.html) with android 2.2 OS must comes with  android market!.if don't have google market that may your phone isn't a [smart phone](http://www.lovebargaining.com/star-a5000-35inch-capacitive-screen-android-22-build-in-gps-wifi-dual-sim-tv-cursor-mouse-cell-phone-p-888.html)!it just only a common phone with MTK OS

Comment: This is the exact reason that I ask this question! ;)

Comment: This is incorrect. There are phones that run Android that do not ship with Google Applications.