# How to install Android Market on HCL ME X1 tablet?

Tags: google-play-store

I bought an HCL ME X1 tablet one month ago. Its main drawback is that it does not support the Android Market and manually installing the Android Market's APK file does not seem to work either. It shows an error message like this:

```
the application Market(process com.android.vending)has stopped unexpectedly) please try again
```

How can I solve this problem so that I can use the Android Market on my device?

Comment: I think you can't. You most likely have bought an Android device without the Google API or do you have an "*with Google (tm)*" text printed somewhere on your device?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7983/how-to-install-android-market-app-manually

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple, step by step guide on how to install the Android Market on the HCL ME X1. It does not require rooting. http://dploy.in/2011/installing-android-market-on-the-hcl-me-x1-coby-kyros-mid7022-without-rooting/

Remember, the HCL ME X1 is nothing but the Coby Kyros MID7022 tablet renamed for the Indian market. So if you're looking for helpful resources on this tablet, you're better of googling around the MID7022 model.

Comment: awesome hint,i will try it to implement

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read in the comments [here](http://arpandeb.com/10/2011/tech/hcl-me-x1-review-of-the-tablet-and-rooting-guide-hands-on-video-and-photographs.html), it sounds like you may need to root the device before you will be able to use the Android Market on it. The page I linked includes instructions on how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to install android market. Just install the old market app after rooting and superuser install. However some apps may not get installed due to compatabiliy issues. Aptoide and 1Mobile market do a good job if u don't want to trouble yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To install android market in your HCL Me tablet, you need to have [adb installed and configured on your system](http://androidtweak.in/general/installing-and-setting-up-android-sdk-adb-and-fastboot-on-gnulinux/)(Linux).
If you are in windows, you need to have necessary drivers for your device.

**To install market, follow the steps.**
1.Connect your device using USB cable.
2.Open terminal and type “adb devices” and confirm that your device recognized on adb.
3.Download latest Android Market, from [here](http://lnx.lu/0JRr) . Or you can download latest [g-apps zip](http://goo.im/gapps/).
4.Extract the contents (apps will be at folder `system/app/Vending.apk`).
5. `adb push /system/app/Vending.apk` (This will copy market apk file to your device)
6. Reboot.

Done!. Login with your gmail account to get market access.
If your device don’t have any other google standard apps (like gtalk), copy the necessary file from the g-app zip file to `/system/app` folder on your device.

More details [here](http://androidtweak.in/rooting/install-android-market-in-hcl-me-series-tablets-x1-ae7-a1-and-am7-a1/)